# React Material-UI get list of items checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have a React + Material-UI frontend. One section allows users to select items from a dropdown and I want the list of whatever the user selects. User can also click x and delete what they selected. How can I use state or some variable to get the final list of items?[image]

CODE:

```
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      className={classes.inputField}
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={userData}

      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.username}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.username}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Users" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current selected values by adding an `onChange` to the Autocomplete component. I have used the Material UI example to show this in action (I am just logging the value to the console -- you will probably want to update a state item):

```
<Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={top100Films}
        onChange={(event, value) => {
          // Printing the current value array
          console.log(value);
        }}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="Multiple values"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
/>
```

The `value` is an array of objects:

[image: screenshot of output]

There's a sandbox of this working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7k682?file=/demo.js) (again, it's using the standard Material UI example code). I have only updated the first Autocomplete component to print the value onChange.